# File download problem in my scala code

Tags: scala

I have written the following scala code to download a file . The file gets downloaded correctly but also an exception is thrown. The code is as follows :

```
var out:OutputStream = null
var in:InputStream = null

      try {
        var url:URL = null
        url = new URL("http://somehost.com/file.doc")
        val uc = url.openConnection()
        val connection = uc.asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
        val buffer:Array[Byte] = new Array[Byte](1024)
        var numRead:Int = 0
        in = connection.getInputStream()
        var localFileName="test.doc"
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFileName))
        while ((numRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
              out.write(buffer,0,numRead);
        }
      }
      catch {
        case e:Exception => println(e.printStackTrace())
      }

      out.close()
      in.close()
```

The file gets downloaded but the following exception is thrown :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:260)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:105)
    at TestDownload$.main(TestDownload.scala:34)
    at TestDownload.main(TestDownload.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
()
```

Why could this be happening and any way to fix it ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scala returns type `Unit`, not the type of the value being assigned, with an assignment statement.  So

```
numRead = in.read(buffer)
```

*never* returns `-1`; it doesn't even return an integer.  You can write

```
while( { numRead = in.read(buffer); numRead != -1 } ) out.write(buffer, 0, numRead)
```

or you can go for a more functional style with

```
Iterator.continually(in.read(buffer)).takeWhile(_ != -1).foreach(n => out.write(buffer,0,n))
```

Personally, I prefer the former since it's shorter (and relies less on iterator evaluation happening the way "it ought to").

Answer (score 2):

An alternative option is to use the system commands which is much cleaner and faster from what I can tell.

```
import sys.process._
import java.net.URL
import java.io.File

new URL("http://somehost.com/file.doc") #> new File("test.doc") !!
```