# IndexOutBoundException While Copying Image File

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
  def saveImages(imageURL : String, destination: String) : String = {
    val file = new URLDataSource(new java.net.URL(imageURL))
    val inputStream = file.getInputStream

    val rootPath : String = "/tmp/"
    val saveFilePath : File = new File(rootPath + destination)
    if(!saveFilePath.exists()) {
      val outputStream: OutputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);
      val b: Array[Byte] = new Array[Byte](1024)
      var length: Int = 0
      while ((length = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(b, 0, length)  //java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown!
      }
      inputStream.close()
      outputStream.close()
    }
    return  saveFilePath.toString;
  }
```

I am using this above code to copy Image file from Image URL to `/tmp/` location, Getting `IndexOutOfBoundException`. How to avoid getting an exception here?

Comment: Got a solution by **Rex Kerr** Please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258283/file-download-problem-in-my-scala-code